# AS3: Toggle button with Button symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Firstly, I have seen many threads about this question but all was about create Toggle button in MovieClip not in Button symbol. I've created Button symbol in Flash Pro.  I defined `Up` And `Over` And `Down` specific states for each of those.

The question is :

How can i create a toggle button with `Button` symbol.

**P.S :**

I'm not talking about create that via MovieClip, i can do it through MovieClip but i need to do that via `Button` symbol. Like below : (MovieClip)

```
var flag:Boolean = false;
myBtn.stop();
myBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

function clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (flag) {
        myBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
    } else { 
        myBtn.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    flag = !flag;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. A button just has the 3 different states + hit zone. So other than creating an extra movieclip in your button and showing / hiding that is not possible.

Comment: So, is there any way to stay on OnMouseDown state in Button ?

Comment: I added an answer below, but I'm curious why you NEED it to be a Button instead of MovieClip. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try swapping around the `downState` and `upState` DisplayObjects when the user clicks the button.

Something like this:

```
function clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var oldUpState:DisplayObject = myBtn.upState;
    myBtn.upState = myBtn.downState;
    myBtn.downState = oldUpState;
}
```